# How to Pass input parameters to Spring restful web service method using model class as inputs & execute MySql stored procedure

Tags: java, mysql, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I'm trying to create an web service in spring & wants to pass inputs to rest controller in json format, for those inputs, i have created an model class with inputs fields & passing to the method, as

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public  Object addEmployee(@RequestBody UserInputModel userInputModel,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    Object result;
    try {           
        result = dataServices.addEntity(userInputModel);            
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();            
        return null;
    }

}
```

Here I'm passing input parameters using rest clients & getting all values "null", can anybody tell me how can i pass values to the method using userInputModel class through rest clients

The input values i'm submitting using rest client as

```
{
"user_id": "",
"user_email_id": "anup@mahjkhjilinator.com",
"user_password": "jhdgfjhgdsjfg",
"firstname": "Anup",
"lastname": "Deshpande",
"mobile_number": "hkhjk",
"user_status": "0",
"isdeleted": "0",
"created_user_id": "1",
"profile_picturename": "anup.jpeg",
"address": "kjhfgkjdfhgfdhk"
```

}

UserInputModel class as:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserInputModel {

//  private final String modelName = "user";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Integer user_id;
    @Column(name = "user_email_id")
    @NotNull
    @Email
    private String user_email_id;
    @Column(name = "user_password")
    private String user_password;
    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstname;
    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastname;
    @NotNull
    // @Phone
    @Size(min = 10, max = 12)
    @Column(name = "mobile_number")
    private String mobile_number;
    @Column(name = "user_status")
    private Integer user_status;
    @Column(name = "isdeleted")
    private Integer isdeleted;
    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private Integer created_by;
    @Column(name = "profile_picturename")
    private String profile_picturename;
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
    public UserInputModel() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public UserInputModel(Integer user_id, String user_email_id,
            String user_password, String firstname, String lastname,
            String mobile_number, Integer user_status, Integer isdeleted,
            Integer created_by, String profile_picturename, String address) {
        super();
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.user_email_id = user_email_id;
        this.user_password = user_password;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.mobile_number = mobile_number;
        this.user_status = user_status;
        this.isdeleted = isdeleted;
        this.created_by = created_by;
        this.profile_picturename = profile_picturename;
        this.address = address;
    }
    public Integer getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(Integer user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public String getUser_email_id() {
        return user_email_id;
    }

    public void setUser_email_id(String user_email_id) {
        this.user_email_id = user_email_id;
    }

    public String getUser_password() {
        return user_password;
    }

    public void setUser_password(String user_password) {
        this.user_password = user_password;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getMobile_number() {
        return mobile_number;
    }

    public void setMobile_number(String mobile_number) {
        this.mobile_number = mobile_number;
    }

    public Integer getUser_status() {
        return user_status;
    }

    public void setUser_status(Integer user_status) {
        this.user_status = user_status;
    }

    public Integer getIsdeleted() {
        return isdeleted;
    }

    public void setIsdeleted(Integer isdeleted) {
        this.isdeleted = isdeleted;
    }

    public Integer getCreated_by() {
        return created_by;
    }

    public void setCreated_by(Integer created_by) {
        this.created_by = created_by;
    }

    public String getProfile_picturename() {
        return profile_picturename;
    }

    public void setProfile_picturename(String profile_picturename) {
        this.profile_picturename = profile_picturename;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

addEntity method code:

```
 @Override
    public User addEntity(UserInputModel userInputModel) throws Exception {
        User user = new User();
        DateTimeUtil dateTimeUtil = new DateTimeUtil();
        Connection con = null;
        CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        try {

            con = new MySqlConnection().getConnection();
            callableStatement = con
                    .prepareCall("{ call sp_user_upsert(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) } ");
            callableStatement.setInt("pv_user_id", userInputModel.getUser_id());
            callableStatement.setString("pv_user_email_id ",
                    userInputModel.getUser_email_id());
            callableStatement.setString("pv_user_password",
                    userInputModel.getUser_password());
            callableStatement.setString("pv_firstname", userInputModel.getFirstname());
            callableStatement.setString("pv_lastname", userInputModel.getLastname());
            callableStatement.setString("pv_mobile_number",
                    userInputModel.getMobile_number());
            callableStatement.setInt("pv_user_status", userInputModel.getUser_status());
            callableStatement.setInt("pv_isdeleted", userInputModel.getIsdeleted());
            callableStatement
                    .setInt("pv_created_user_id", userInputModel.getCreated_by());
            callableStatement.setString("pv_profile_picturename",
                    userInputModel.getProfile_picturename());
            callableStatement.setString("pv_address", userInputModel.getAddress());
            resultSet = callableStatement.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                user.setUser_id(resultSet.getInt("user_id"));
                user.setUser_email_id(resultSet.getString("user_email_id"));
                user.setUser_password(resultSet.getString("user_password"));
                user.setFirstname(resultSet.getString("firstname"));
                user.setLastname(resultSet.getString("lastname"));
                user.setRole_id(resultSet.getInt("role_id"));
                user.setMobile_number(resultSet.getString("mobile_number"));
                user.setUser_status(resultSet.getInt("user_status"));
                user.setCreated_by(resultSet.getInt("created_by"));
                user.setCreated_date(resultSet.getString("created_date"));
                user.setModified_by(resultSet.getInt("modified_by"));
                user.setModified_date(resultSet.getString("modified_date"));
                user.setIsdeleted(resultSet.getInt("isdeleted"));
                user.setOldpassword(resultSet.getString("oldpassword"));
                user.setProfile_picturename(resultSet
                        .getString("profile_picturename"));
                user.setAddress(resultSet.getString("address"));

//              user.setUser_id(resultSet.getInt("user_id"));

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (resultSet != null)
                resultSet.close();
            if (callableStatement != null)
                callableStatement.close();
            if (con != null)
                con.close();
        }
        return user;
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show what you are submitting.

Comment: Hi, updated question, plz check 1s & let me know where do i need to make changes.

Comment: That isn't going to work, obviously. Binding/conversion is done by using the name to find the property on the object then set the value. Now you would need to have a property named `inputs` on your `UserInputModel` which would probably need a `Map` to hold all the parameters.

Comment: if i passe parameters only in key & value pair, that time i'm getting "400 Bad  request" message on my rest client. can you tell me how can i create an property for input model to hold parameters??, that will be an great help

Comment: can you post your model class and what code you have written in addEntity?

Comment: Your son properties need to match the java properties, if you have a property `name` on your object there should be a `name` property in the json you submit.

Comment: Updated question with model class & addEntity code check 1s

Comment: Parameters you are setting in addEntity, should me mentioned in your controller class addEmployee. And in rest client you should pass same to add the data.. in addEmployee, you are directly calling dataServices.addEntity(userInputModel). so it is going null values. And inputs u giving in Array format, but in your code there is no code for array declaration

Comment: @arch, can u tell me how to pass input parameters without for addEntity

Comment: @AnupDeshpande has it worked for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public  Response addEmployee(@RequestBody UserInputModel userInputModel,
            JSONObject json) {
        Response result;
        try { 
               String pv_user_email_id = "";
                if(json.has("pv_user_email_id")){
                    pv_user_email_id = json.getString("pv_user_email_id");
                }  

              Integer id =0;
              if(json.has("id")){
                    id = json.getInt("id");
                }

              userInputModel.setUser_email_id(pv_user_email_id);
              userInputModel.setId(id);

            result = dataServices.addEntity(userInputModel);            
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();            
            return null;
        }

    }
```

JSON Input to be given:

```
   {
    "pv_user_email_id":"user@gmail.com",
    "pv_user_password":"1234"
    "id":2
    }
```

Please refere above code and make changes accordingly. I have given example for one parameter, you follow the same for all the parameters you are using in model class.